# Regexp matching all occurrencies of some text within given text (no spaces\words in text, text is one line)

Tags: java, regex

What regexp matches all occurrencies of origModifiedTime in below output?

This output is a single line (end-of-line symbols are at the very end), there are no spaces (words). It is output (log) of ArrayList containing several instances of some class. I need to see value of one certain field in all those instances.

I need this regexp to highlight these words in console output (using GrepConsole eclipse plugin, it promises to highlight regexp-matched parts).

> [model.AudioRecord@622ebecd[id=7,importance=MID,cramFlag=false,topicGroup=IT,topic=Java,subTopic=,Comment=,searchTags=,chekoutDate=,nextReviewDate=,reviewHistory=,trackedName=812_1206_200.WMA,origName=812_1206,origModifiedTime=2017-06-15T19:22:16,fileSize=838408],
>   model.AudioRecord@2d12e7d2[id=6,importance=MID,cramFlag=false,topicGroup=IT,topic=Java,subTopic=,Comment=,searchTags=,chekoutDate=,nextReviewDate=,reviewHistory=,trackedName=812_1210_580.WMA,origName=812_1210,origModifiedTime=2017-06-13T21:51:38,fileSize=1172952],
>   model.AudioRecord@3e363ecc[id=5,importance=MID,cramFlag=false,topicGroup=IT,topic=Java,subTopic=,Comment=,searchTags=,chekoutDate=,nextReviewDate=,reviewHistory=,trackedName=812_1210.WMA,origName=812_1210,origModifiedTime=2017-01-17T20:09:48,fileSize=1172952],
>   model.AudioRecord@29f93711[id=4,importance=MID,cramFlag=false,topicGroup=IT,topic=Java,subTopic=,Comment=,searchTags=,chekoutDate=,nextReviewDate=,reviewHistory=,trackedName=812_1209.WMA,origName=812_1209,origModifiedTime=2017-01-17T18:15:50,fileSize=2720218],
>   model.AudioRecord@5faad73e[id=3,importance=MID,cramFlag=false,topicGroup=IT,topic=Java,subTopic=,Comment=,searchTags=,chekoutDate=,nextReviewDate=,reviewHistory=,trackedName=812_1208.WMA,origName=812_1208,origModifiedTime=2017-01-16T23:45:42,fileSize=12320436],
>   model.AudioRecord@653c876e[id=2,importance=MID,cramFlag=false,topicGroup=IT,topic=Java,subTopic=,Comment=,searchTags=,chekoutDate=,nextReviewDate=,reviewHistory=,trackedName=812_1207.WMA,origName=812_1207,origModifiedTime=2017-01-15T02:54:26,fileSize=3831382],
>   model.AudioRecord@6a73055b[id=1,importance=MID,cramFlag=false,topicGroup=IT,topic=Java,subTopic=,Comment=,searchTags=,chekoutDate=,nextReviewDate=,reviewHistory=,trackedName=812_1206.WMA,origName=812_1206,origModifiedTime=2017-01-15T00:22:34,fileSize=838408]]

Comment: Asking for a regex is the same as asking for any other programming code. This is not what StackOverflow is for. Please do some research, show your own effort and explain where you encountered a problem in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`(?<=origModifiedTime)(.*)(?=,)/gU`

It uses a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead to match anything between a certain two characters.

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/re6Tfi/1